# Showing "No data available in table" on sorting and searching data

Tags: angularjs, datatable

Below is my table's html code -

```
<table id="srchTable" style="width:100%; font-size:0.85em;"">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Age</th>
     <th>Salary</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tr ng-repeat="jsonSearchData in searchData">
   <td><a id="link1" href="" ng-click="openPopUp()">{{jsonSearchData.Name}}</a></td>
   <td>{{jsonSearchData.Age}}</td>
   <td>{{jsonSearchData.Salary}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

This is js code for table -

```
$('#srchTable').dataTable();
```

I am populating table from json result. Below is the json -

```
[{  
      "Name":"Sam",
      "Age":"25",
      "Salary":"$25000"
 },
 {
      "Name":"Phillip",
      "Age":"25",
      "Salary":"$30000"
 }]
```

Now when I am clicking on sort icons table is showing `No data available in table` message. And same thing is happeing when I am trying to search in data table.
I tried below code but it didn't worked.

```
$('#srchTable').dataTable({
  "ordering":true,
  "searching": true
});
```

Please help.

Comment: I think, that code `$('#srchTable').dataTable()` run before the angular render table. Please try `setTimeout(function() { $('#srchTable').dataTable() }, 1000);` for test, and say me if it work

Comment: @LinnTroll - Its not working. :(

Comment: so looking at this question, after making some comments on the other question you posted, I can see that you already tried to ask about the problem.  What I am seeing here and in your other question is a common theme, you are trying to think of Angular.js in the same way you might think of jQuery, even though they accomplish things ***very differently***.  **DON'T** use jQuery with angular unless you are designing new functionality.  This is a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542?s=2|0.8371#15012542

Answer (score 1):

In this case jquery is executed before angular render the data .
You don't need to use jquery here. Angular provides [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) 
 and [sorting](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) options .

example :

```
  <input type="search" ng-model="query">
    <table id="srchTable" style="width:100%; font-size:0.85em;"">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Age</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tr ng-repeat="jsonSearchData in searchData | filter : query | orderBy : 'name'">
       <td><a id="link1" href="" ng-click="openPopUp()">{{jsonSearchData.Name}}   </a></td>
       <td>{{jsonSearchData.Age}}</td>
       <td>{{jsonSearchData.Salary}}</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Your solution is working, but it is sorting name when first table is loaded. As i click on sort icons its showing me `No data available in table`.

Comment: Don't use any jquery here. Angular is automatically sorting the data based on name.

Comment: Follow angularjs docs for more sorting options : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: I tried order by, but the default sorting that is enabled on data table is not working.

Answer (score 0):

**Be sure to wrap your data rows in `<tbody></tbody>`.**

```
        <table id="srchTable" style="width:100%; font-size:0.85em;"">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Age</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>

<tbody><!-- start after </thead> Be sure not to include in loop -->

     <tr ng-repeat="jsonSearchData in searchData">
       <td><a id="link1" href="" ng-click="openPopUp()">{{jsonSearchData.Name}}</a></td>
       <td>{{jsonSearchData.Age}}</td>
       <td>{{jsonSearchData.Salary}}</td>
     </tr>

</tbody><!-- end after loop -->

</table>
```